# trigger code in shiny app when user click on sign out - shinyproxy

Tags: r, shiny, shinyproxy

I have a shinyapp taken in production with `shinyproxy`.

When user click sign out from shinyproxy i.e
[image]

I'd like to be able to trigger inside my app some brief computation, but `OnStop` or `session$onSessionEnded()` doesn't seem to work in this case, they work only when user close the browser tab.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: This is an `actionButton`, right? Did you try using `observeEvent` with this input?

Comment: it's different from a button inside shiny. From source code of html page it doesn't seem to have an id associated that i can use inside observeEvent. Furthermore I don't know if the app could "know" what's happening in shinyproxy. Shinyproxy basically orchestrate the way how multiple user/app interact, i don't know if an app can recieve some input from it.